# Is there a way to obtain polyline of pbf file?

Tags: openstreetmap, pbf, osmium

I need to find boundaries of pbf file. Ideally - polyline, if this not possible - can be simple(min,max lat,lon rectangle). I download pbf from geofabrik(http://download.geofabrik.de/russia/northwestern-fed-district.html).

I try to obtain boundaries with

```
01:14:35 robots@HQ import → osmium fileinfo -eg data.bbox northwestern-fed-district-latest.osm.pbf 
[======================================================================] 100% 
(10.2919599,51.2626864,105.9294632,84.694631)
```

But this bbox seems to incorrect(Or I am doing something wrong).

However. I see on geofabrik web-page for downloading areas, on top right corner there is a map with an area of the pbf I am downloading and that is why I am pretty sure, that I somehow can extract this information from pbf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the polyline from the geofabrik.de link you've quoted in your question. It's right here: `.poly file that describes the extent of this region.`.

Note that this polygon was used to extract data from an OSM planet via the osmium tools. You're likely not able reconstruct the original polygon used for extracting the data from the resulting osm.pbf file, as there may be simply no data available in some parts of the OSM planet.

As an example, the actual limits of your extract in the Barents Sea was probably drawn by hand, and you wouldn't be able to determine the exact limits of the polygon due to lack of data.

Comment: Oh, where are my eyes... 

Marking this as a correct. Btw, do you know any reasons why osmium fails to get the true boundaries of pbf? I mean they are completely wrong, not just not accurate

Comment: Depending on the extract strategy (see https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#creating-geographic-extracts -> Extract strategies), the extract can also include objects which are only referenced by objects inside the polygon. In your case, there are likely very large boundary objects that cause the resulting bbox to be quite large.

Comment: Ah, okay, got it. Seems reasonable for me, that can be an explanation. Thank you.